# How to export ply file with RGB color

Tags: export

I want to export ply file of an object in a format like below.

```
    ply
    format ascii 1.0
    element vertex 460
    property double x
    property double y
    property double z
    property uchar red
    property uchar green
    property uchar blue
    end_header
    -0.560615837574 1.62521636486 3.65350723267 109 111 88
    0.191478937864 1.66052913666 3.68975090981 85 67 33
    0.0531006716192 1.45623040199 3.91900682449 135 118 80
    0.546797394753 1.55062174797 3.91575264931 55 53 33
    -0.158744961023 1.66237902641 3.86506175995 64 56 41
    -0.0506650619209 1.38843286037 3.61278986931 66 64 48
    -0.520196318626 1.27587473392 3.85415959358 52 59 39
```

However, after exporting from Blender(file>export>Stanford(.ply)), I get a file contents as below

```
    ply
    format ascii 1.0
    comment Created by Blender 2.79 (sub 0) - www.blender.org, source file: ''
    element vertex 8
    property float x
    property float y
    property float z
    element face 6
    property list uchar uint vertex_indices
    end_header
    1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
    1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
    -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
    -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
    1.000000 0.999999 1.000000
    -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
    -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
    0.999999 -1.000001 1.000000
    4 0 1 2 3
    4 4 5 6 7
    4 0 4 7 1
    4 1 7 6 2
    4 2 6 5 3
    4 4 0 3 5
```

So, how can I include RGB value in .ply file?

Comment: Add vertex colors to the mesh.